# java.awt.Robot uses weird settings for screen resolution at 4k screen

Tags: java

I have a 4k screen which is 3840x2160 pixels. I'm trying to use `java.awt.Robot` to click certain things, which require exact accuracy, but robot missclicks. I tried to find out what's wrong and found out that

```
getLocalGraphicsEnvironment
.getDefaultScreenDevice
.getDefaultConfiguration
.getBounds
```

returns `java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=3351,height=1885]` instead of desired 3840x2160.
I can determine screen size from other sources and create transformation but i want to find out what's the source of this number and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a high-res display with a scale transformation.

For windows this is typically configured in the display settings:
[image]

To overcome this behavior of `Robot` you could use [`createMultiResolutionScreenCapture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html#createMultiResolutionScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) introduced in java11

```kotlin
val robot = Robot()

val rectangle = Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().screenSize)
val downscaled = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle)

val multiResCapture = robot.createMultiResolutionScreenCapture(rectangle)
val fullHD: Image = multiResCapture.resolutionVariants.last()
```